# Mouse buttons and keyboard stop working for no apparent reason. Xubuntu 22.04

Tags: keyboard, xubuntu, mouse, xfce

I have a new Lenovo Ideapad, running Xubuntu 22.04. It stays on all the time, with an occasional suspend. Occasionally (e.g. every 2 or 3 days) mouse buttons and keyboard stop working. The mouse cursor continues to move. I can ssh onto it and all seems well as far as I can tell. "top" doesn't show any processes doing anything bad, and the machine is around 98% idle.

If I kill Xorg or xfce-session, it comes back to the login screen and everything works. (Of course all my applications have died.)

So it doesn't look like any sort of hardware problem.

Any ideas as to further investigative steps I can take? Or any way I might be able to recover without killing the session?

Log info as requested by @Daniel T:

dmesg: The only message around the time this happened was:

```
[Sun Feb  4 10:14:51 2024] perf: interrupt took too long (4990 > 4968), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 40000
```

which doesn't look relevant, especially as similar happened at other times.

Here's what's at the end of Xorg.log for the Xorg instance that I killed. I guess "event 7" and following lines are the result of my killing the process. The 3 lines before that occur repeatedly, but do not seem to be linked to the problem occurring:

```
[140756.767] (II) modeset(0): EDID vendor "CMN", prod id 5456
[140756.767] (II) modeset(0): Printing DDC gathered Modelines:
[140756.767] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1920x1080"x0.0  138.78  1920 1968 2000 2080  1080 1090 1096 1112 -hsync -vsync (66.7 kHz eP)
[140884.540] (II) event7  - Video Bus: device removed
[140884.572] (II) event1  - Power Button: device removed
[140884.596] (II) event5  - Optical Mouse: device removed
[140884.664] (II) event3  - CIRQ1000:00 0488:1014 Mouse: device removed
[140884.712] (II) event6  - Ideapad extra buttons: device removed
[140884.728] (II) event2  - AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: device removed
[140884.750] (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
[140884.750] (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
[140884.750] (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
[140884.750] (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
[140884.751] (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
[140884.751] (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
[140884.751] (II) UnloadModule: "synaptics"
[140884.836] (II) Server terminated successfully (0). Closing log file.
```

I can run xeyes from an ssh session and it appears, but the eyes do not follow the mouse cursor. Oddly, when I kill xeyes (either Ctrl-C or pkill), it doesn't disappear immediately. Sometimes, the screen blanks; sometimes the eyes disappear at the moment that I move the mouse. I'm afraid it's hard to characterize the behaviour exactly. I wonder if there's a massive (but random) delay in X events being handled, and any correlation I've perceived has been apparent rather than real. Sometimes the eyes take a long time to appear; and they're not always looking in the same direction - maybe they look where they think the mouse was at the time. (When the machine is not in this "frozen" state, the eyes do move correctly. I'm running Xorg; XDG_SESSION_TYPE=x11)

Here is output from journalctl --user -r, from shortly before I noticed the latest "freeze":

```
Feb 04 17:16:02 ideapad pkexec[17470]: pam_unix(polkit-1:session): session opened for user root(uid=0) by (uid=1027)
Feb 04 17:16:50 ideapad xfce4-screensav[13164]: gdk_monitor_get_scale_factor: assertion 'GDK_IS_MONITOR (monitor)' failed
Feb 04 17:16:50 ideapad xfce4-screensav[13164]: gdk_monitor_get_scale_factor: assertion 'GDK_IS_MONITOR (monitor)' failed
Feb 04 17:16:50 ideapad xfce4-screensav[13164]: gdk_monitor_get_scale_factor: assertion 'GDK_IS_MONITOR (monitor)' failed
Feb 04 17:16:50 ideapad xfce4-screensav[13164]: gdk_monitor_get_scale_factor: assertion 'GDK_IS_MONITOR (monitor)' failed
Feb 04 17:16:50 ideapad xfce4-screensav[13164]: gdk_monitor_get_scale_factor: assertion 'GDK_IS_MONITOR (monitor)' failed
Feb 04 17:16:50 ideapad xfce4-screensav[13164]: gdk_monitor_get_workarea: assertion 'GDK_IS_MONITOR (monitor)' failed
Feb 04 17:16:50 ideapad xfce4-screensav[13164]: gdk_monitor_get_workarea: assertion 'GDK_IS_MONITOR (monitor)' failed
Feb 04 17:18:50 ideapad pkexec[17531]: pam_unix(polkit-1:session): session opened for user root(uid=0) by (uid=1027)
Feb 04 17:19:43 ideapad pkexec[17535]: pam_unix(polkit-1:session): session opened for user root(uid=0) by (uid=1027)
Feb 04 17:21:34 ideapad xfce4-screensav[13164]: invalid uninstantiatable type '<unknown>' in cast to 'GSWindow'
Feb 04 17:38:28 ideapad pkexec[18153]: pam_unix(polkit-1:session): session opened for user root(uid=0) by (uid=1027)
Feb 04 17:43:20 ideapad pkexec[18170]: pam_unix(polkit-1:session): session opened for user root(uid=0) by (uid=1027)
Feb 04 17:55:13 ideapad pkexec[18457]: pam_unix(polkit-1:session): session opened for user root(uid=0) by (uid=1027)
Feb 04 18:02:10 ideapad sudo[18493]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
```

I have switched desktops, to gnome-session-flashback, to see if that helps. If the problem doesn't recur after, say, 4 days, I'll assume that it's fixed. I'd be happy to try further tests if someone is interested in getting to the bottom of this.

Final update (probably): It's been running for 8 days on gnome-session-flashback without the problem recurring. I'm disappointed not to have been able to find why xfce and the Ideapad don't get along with each other, but I'm just going to stick with gnome-session-flashback now. (BTW, I have an old Dell Latitude running xfce with no problem.)  Thanks again for everyone's input.

Comment: This looks like part of the GPU software froze. The mouse cursor is handled by a specialized layer of the GPU, so it moving does not mean the code running on the GPU is alive. What are your Xorg.0.log and dmesg?

Comment: Let's test the alternative hypothesis that GNOME is frozen, not the GPU. Go to CTRL+ALT+F1 and make sure `DISPLAY=:0 xeyes` on an unfrozen state works first. Switch back with CTRL+ALT+F8 or another. Then once it's frozen, see if launching xeyes is still able to get anything to show up.

Comment: The eyes not following the cursor could mean that you're in Wayland. Are you in Wayland (try checking $WAYLAND_DISPLAY)? You might also find details about your error in `journalctl --user -r`